# Do I need a separate thread to set a timer for a while loop in the main program?

Tags: c, timer

I want to run a loop for a specified amount of time, but right now all I can think of is create a timer-based thread, and use a signal to tell the main function when it's finally over.

The requirement is that I'm seeking to be able to set a specific amount of milliseconds timer, while the object of interest is moving throughout an environment. So lets say I know the velocity, yet have no feedback of the position, I can predict what position I'm in. 
(i.e. rotating at 5 rad/s, determine how much time I need to rotate 90 degrees).

maybe something like the following hypothetical program.

```
static sem_t timerSem;  
static bool timerExp;
pthread_t th_timer;

static void timersignaldhandler()
{
    sem_post(&timerSem);
}

void *th_timer(void *)
{
      while(!timer_stopped){
            int rc = sem_wait(&timerSem);
            timer_func();
      }
}
void shutdown_timer() 
{
    timerExp = true;
    sem_post(&timerSem);
    pthread_join(th_timer, 0);
}
void timer_func() 
{
    //sleep for x mS

    //Shutdown
    shutdown_timer();
    sem_post(&demo_over);   // signal main thread to exit
}
move()
{
     //Move command
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{    
     timerExp = false;
     pthread_create(&th_timer, NULL, th_timer, NULL);


     while(!timerExp)
     {
           move();
     }
}
```

Is this the ideal approach? do I need even need a separate timer thread?

Comment: The `alarm()` system call allows you to set a SIGALRM to appear in an integral number of seconds, without requiring a second thread.  There are sub-second equivalents available with [`setitimer()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setitimer.html), which can be persuaded to generate a SIGALRM too.  Don't try using both `alarm()` and `setitimer()`; the behaviour is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think you need to do separate thread.

Why not do something like this, this program will run for 30 seconds

```
int t =  time(NULL);
int i = 0;
while(t+30 > time(NULL)) {
   ++i;
   // or do whatever in here
}
```

Comment: While this is valid for seconds, OP mentions miliseconds in his question.

Comment: That's not often a good way to do things.  There are several problems. It leads to a form of busy waiting (if there's nothing in the 'do whatever' code, then it pounds on the CPU without doing anything useful).  Conversely, if the 'do whatever' code takes too long (many seconds, perhaps because it was waiting for a network message), there can be a long gap between the iteration before 30 seconds is up and when the time is spotted as being over 30 seconds later.

Comment: should work, especially after correcting the two calls to 'time()'  the proper format is : 'time_t t = time(NULL);'.  Using the suggested method, the program will run for (between) 30 and 31 seconds.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler you are right, but I was just pointing him in right direction.

Comment: Wouldn't this approach slow down the process inside the while loop?
and can this achieve an accuracy of 1ms?

Comment: it would not slow anything inside the loop but it would not be precise indeed since time() uses seconds. There is way to measure milliseconds